# Parameterize Java JPA ALTER SESSION SQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, code-injection, fortify

I am having a problem with setting a parameter in an SQL `Query` statement created from a JPA `EntityManager`.
I am working in an EJB and the `EntityManager` object for the session is valid.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

pubic void methodWorks(EntityManager em, String schema) {
    String sqlStmt = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = " + schema;
    try {
        em.createNativeQuery(sqlStmt).executeUpdate();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
pubic void methodFails1(EntityManager em, String schema) {
    String sqlStmt = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ?";
    try {
        em.createNativeQuery(sqlStmt).setParameter(1, schema).executeUpdate();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
pubic void methodFails2(EntityManager em, String schema) {
    String sqlStmt = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ?1";
    try {
        em.createNativeQuery(sqlStmt).setParameter(1, schema).executeUpdate();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
pubic void methodFails3(EntityManager em, String schema) {
    String sqlStmt = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = :inputSchema";
    try {
        em.createNativeQuery(sqlStmt).setParameter("inputSchema", schema).executeUpdate();
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that a Fortify Scan (**which this must pass**) identifies the `sqlStmt` in the `methodWorks` method as being vulnerable to an SQL Injection Attack (from Fortify). The failed methods all report

```
Internal Exception java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA:-02421 mission or invalid schema authorization identifier.
Error Code 2421
Call: ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ?
   bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

Merely sanitizing the input parameter "isn't good enough" to pass the Fortify and QA.
Setting it as a parameter (which hint-hint: CAN be easily fooled) will pass the Fortify scan and QA requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This query is indeed open to SQL injection because you're using string concatenation.
The safe way to handle a query like this is to use parameters.

```
String sqlStmt = "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ?";
Query updateQuery = em.createNativeQuery(sqlStmt);

updateQuery.setParameter(0, schema);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Parameter values are automatically escaped for you. This saves you time as you don't need to worry about SQL injection any longer. This is solved in the Query/EntityManager class.
Also, it makes the query a lot easier to read.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answering, but that is pretty much `methodFails1`. Also, I initially tried (what I thought would have been correct) a 0 based parameter list. This throws an exception to that effect.
However, after a lengthy search, I was able to turn up "...statement 'alter session set current_schema=SCHEMA' to switch object visibility... **is a DDL statement** and **does not support bind variable placeholders**... 
So I am now looking for a way that Fortify will overlook the SQL Insertion vulnerability.